# Apply CSS style to every 8th element in the container

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors

I have div's with each an id (0, 1, 2, 3 etc.) and they all have a width of 200 px, however I want to assign a width of 500px to the div that comes after 8 div's, so div 8, div 16, div 24 etc.

Is this possible with css only or should I use a combination of jquery (each)?

This is what I have now:

```
div.blogbloglayout .items-row.row-0 .voucher, 
div.blogbloglayout .items-row.row-8 .voucher {
    height:500px;
}
```

But this should be done automatically, not like I did above. Couldn't find an answer related to this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`nth-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child).

I should point out that applying the style to the first item in the container wouldn't follow your pattern. You could add `div.blogbloglayout .items-row:first-child .voucher` to the selector though.

```css
div.blogbloglayout .items-row .voucher {
    background:#F66;
    width:200px;
}

div.blogbloglayout .items-row:nth-child(8n) .voucher {
    width:500px;
}
```

```html
<div class='blogbloglayout'>
    <div class='items-row'><div class='voucher'>Voucher</div></div>
    <div class='items-row'><div class='voucher'>Voucher</div></div>
    <div class='items-row'><div class='voucher'>Voucher</div></div>
    <div class='items-row'><div class='voucher'>Voucher</div></div>
    <div class='items-row'><div class='voucher'>Voucher</div></div>
    <div class='items-row'><div class='voucher'>Voucher</div></div>
    <div class='items-row'><div class='voucher'>Voucher</div></div>
    <div class='items-row'><div class='voucher'>Voucher</div></div>
    <div class='items-row'><div class='voucher'>Voucher</div></div>
    <div class='items-row'><div class='voucher'>Voucher</div></div>
    <div class='items-row'><div class='voucher'>Voucher</div></div>
    <div class='items-row'><div class='voucher'>Voucher</div></div>
    <div class='items-row'><div class='voucher'>Voucher</div></div>
    <div class='items-row'><div class='voucher'>Voucher</div></div>
    <div class='items-row'><div class='voucher'>Voucher</div></div>
    <div class='items-row'><div class='voucher'>Voucher</div></div>
    <div class='items-row'><div class='voucher'>Voucher</div></div>
    <div class='items-row'><div class='voucher'>Voucher</div></div>
    <div class='items-row'><div class='voucher'>Voucher</div></div>
    <div class='items-row'><div class='voucher'>Voucher</div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great, didn't know I could apply css like this. I was aware of nth-child() but I thought it only applied to even/odd (as is shown in most examples..)